# Query activity : To group a field based on Account ID

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql

I have a data extension (DE_A) that has following coloumns:

Column 1: Account ID (no duplicates),
Column 2: Date (the field is date)

I have another data extension (DE_B) that is subset of DE_A filtered for a certain period of date. So DE_B has the values only for example last month. It has another column called Amount.

Column 1: Account ID (with duplicates),
Column 2: Amount (the field is currency)

My requirement is to add the 'Amount' figure for each Account ID that exists both in DE_A and DE_B. Update this sum as the third column in DE_A. Is it possible using query activity? If so how?

Sorry guys, I am confused about how to implement this as I am a Noob on query activity. My idea is to add one more column to DE_A called total_amount and run this query :

```
select 
a.account_id
, b.account_id
, sum(b.amount) as a.total_amount
from DE_A as a
INNER JOIN DE_B as b on (a.account_id = b.account_id)
GROUP BY b.account_id;
```

Will this work?

Comment: Hey, @mitt88, have you tried anything?  If so, can you update your question with some details?

Comment: It's a simple query. Please share what you have tried and I can help you with that

Comment: Hello Maneesh, please see the updated  as to what I am going to try once I get access to SFMC. Can you check this'?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I tried the following query to query 2 different data extensions and put the result into a third one. This itself is not working as its giving a syntax error (Error: The query syntax is invalid
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.) Could you help me with this. The query I tried is as below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for giving it a shot.

Column aliases can't reference the table aliases and you've got two `account_id` columns, which won't work.

Also, you don't have to `select` every column you plan on using in your `where` or `group by`.

Here's how I'd write it:

```
select 
a.account_id
, sum(b.amount) as total_amount
from DE_A as a
INNER JOIN DE_B as b on (a.account_id = b.account_id)
GROUP BY b.account_id
```